# It is possible to add or remove UDIDs to an existing provisioning profile using the terminal?

Tags: ios, terminal, provisioning, udid

There is a way, using the command line, to add and remove UDIDs from an iOS Adhoc provisioning profile?

Comment: No! Its not possible, please read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW10

Comment: Thanks Jeneena. I was wondering if there is a way to make that process in a more automated way. We use to send apps to testers, and each time there is a new user UDID, we need to do the register process in the Apple Developer account, and is quite time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to regenerate the profile, but you should be able to automate the generation of them using fastlane: https://fastlane.tools

Comment: Alex, thank you very much. The fastlane set of tools seems impressive, I'll give it a try.